# Improper Integral of the Dawson's integral

Tags: integration, limits, improper-integrals

I run into the Dawson's integral during my research of solving this integral ([Coupled complex double integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3601960/coupled-complex-double-integral)). But why is the integral of Dawson's integral not converting.

The limits of the Dawson's integral are

$$
F(x)=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt(\pi) \exp(-x^2) \int_0^{x} \exp{(t^2)} \, dt 
$$
$$
\lim_{x \to \pm\infty} F(x) = 0
$$

Telling me, there is an enclosed area under the graph. However, the integral of the the dawson integral

$$
\int_0^{\infty} F(x) dx
$$

is not converting based on wolframalpha. Do I miss a basic understanding of integrals and integration?

Comment: A function can go to zero as $x$ goes to infinity while still have an infinite improper integral over that domain.

Comment: Frankly speaking, I can hardly imagine this properties in terms of an area under a graph. Does that mean the function has some singularities within the limts. Is there something I can conclude from such a behaviour?

Comment: The function $1/\sqrt{x}$ goes to zero in the limit, but the area under the curve is still infinite.

Comment: I know you are right, but, that somehow breaks my understanding of limits and integrals. if you know what I mean. I think I have to get another perspective on this issue. Thanks btw, its always helpful to talk to someone rather than mind trap myself.

Comment: Maybe try the indefenite integral by converting the erfi(x) and exp($-x^2$) to summations and integrating. Solve the integral and evaluate from 0 to $\infty$ to see it diverges. Here is a modified integral which converges:[with exp(-x) in integrand](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=∫F%28x%29exp%28-x%29dx+from+0+to+∞). Also:[with $x^{-2}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=∫F%28x%29x%5E-2dx+from+1+to+∞). These converge among others.